# django models, applying filter() on joined table with extra()

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying this:

```
count = UserCheck.objects.filter(user=puser, fixture__competition__name__icontains='gold',
                                   fixture__date__gte='2013-02-11',
                                   fixture__date__lte='2013-05-24', year=2013).extra(
                                   where=["WEEKOFYEAR(fixture__date) = %s" %week]).exclude(result=0).count()
```

The problem is the `extra()` part where I can't filter using `WEEKOFYEAR(fixture__date)`. How can I do this. Is this possible?

PS: I am using MySQL (and django 1.4)

Comment: have you tried `["WEEKOFYEAR(app_fixture.data = %s" % week]`?

Comment: right. Make it an answer so I can accept it!(just use `date` instead of `data`) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) QuerySet modifier, you are not using Django's ORM anymore. You are using "pure" SQL, so basically related models can't be accessed with the `__` notation and in your case `fixture__date` is not a valid column name. However, one must keep in mind that tables are named in a specific way in Django. So you can use:

```
count = UserCheck.objects.filter(user=puser, fixture__competition__name__icontains='gold',
                                   fixture__date__gte='2013-02-11',
                                   fixture__date__lte='2013-05-24', year=2013).extra(
                                   where=["WEEKOFYEAR(app_fixture.date) = %s" %week]).exclude(result=0).count()
```

where `app` refers to the app that holds the `Fixture` model.

In short, for each model in an app, Django makes the table `<app>_<model>`, and you can use that with the `extra` clause when you want to refer to that model.